# How to add data to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I have a problem. I need to fill rows in mysql db with data from four textbox on a form, the problem is that when I open the page automatically inserts "element_1", "element_2" etc.. in the db. 
This is because I have definitely wrong values ​​inserted in the query, but since I am noob to php, I do not know how to declare the variable and assign it to the text field. 
Below is an image of the form.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6ACM.png

EDIT: NOW I have this code!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Aggiungi Prodotto</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="top.png" width="400px" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">               

                            <?php 

                                include '../config.php'; 

                                $data = new MysqlClass();
                                $data->connetti();

                                $element1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['element_1']);
                                $element2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['element_2']);
                                $element31 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['element_3_1']);
                                $element4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['element_4']);

                                if (isset($_POST["element_1"]) && isset($_POST["element_2"]) && isset($_POST["element_3"]) && isset($_POST["element_4"]));
                                $post_sql = $data->query("INSERT INTO `intse`.`products` (`id`, `name`, `cat`, `price`) VALUES ('".$_POST['element_1']."', '".$_POST['element_2']."', '".$_POST['element_4']."', '".$_POST['element_3_1']."');"); 

                                echo '<form id="form_824225" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">';    
                                echo '<div class="form_description">';
                                echo '<h2>Aggiungi Prodotto</h2>';    
                                echo '<p>Aggiunta Manuale Nuovo Prodotto</p>';
                                echo '</div>';
                                echo '<ul >';
                                echo '<li id="li_1" >';
                                echo '<label class="description" for="element_1">Cod. ID </label>';
                                echo '<div>';
                                echo '<input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text small" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>';
                                echo '</div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_1"><small>Specifica Codice ID Interno</small></p>';
                                echo '</li><li id="li_2" >';
                                echo '<label class="description" for="element_2">Nome Prodotto </label>';
                                echo '<div>';
                                echo '<input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>';
                                echo '</div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_2"><small>Specifica Nome Prodotto</small></p>';
                                echo '</li><li id="li_4" >';
                                echo '<label class="description" for="element_4">Categoria </label>';
                                echo '<div>';
                                echo '<select class="element select medium" id="element_4" name="element_4">';
                                echo '<option value="" selected="selected">Scegli...</option>';
                                echo '<option value="1" >Desktop PC</option>';
                                echo '<option value="2" >Mini PC</option>';
                                echo '<option value="3" >Gaming PC</option>';
                                echo '<option value="4" >Office PC</option>';
                                echo '<option value="5" >Server PC</option>';
                                echo '<option value="6" >Accessori</option>';
                                echo '</select>';
                                echo '</div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_4"><small>Specifica Categoria Prodotto</small></p>';
                                echo '</li><li id="li_3" >';
                                echo '<li id="li_5">';
                                echo '<label class="description" for="element_3">Prezzo </label></li>';
                                echo '<span>';
                                echo '<input id="element_3_1" name="element_3_1" class="element text currency" size="10" value="0" type="text" /> ,00 €';
                                echo '</span>';
                                echo '<p class="guidelines" id="guide_3"><small>Specifica il prezzo praticato al dettaglio.</small></p> ';
                                echo '</li>';
                                echo '<li class="buttons">';
                                echo '<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="824225" />';
                                echo '<input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Aggiungi" />';
                                echo '</li>';
                                echo '</ul>';
                                echo '</form>';

                                if(mysql_num_rows($post_sql) > 0) {

                                    while($post_obj = $data->estrai($post_sql)) {

                                        $id = $post_obj['element_1'];
                                        $name = stripcslashes($post_obj['element_2']);
                                        $cat = stripcslashes($post_obj['element_4']);
                                        $price = stripcslashes($post_obj['element_3_1']);
                                  }
                                } else {

                                    echo 'Errore DATABASE';

                                }

                                $data->disconnetti();
                            ?>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
    <img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the config.php file:

```
<?php

class MysqlClass {

    private $nomehost = 'localhost';     
    private $nomeuser = 'root';          
    private $password = 'xxxxx'; 
    private $nomedb = 'intse';
    private $attiva = FALSE;
    private $connessione;

    public function connetti() {

        if(!$this->attiva && ($this->connessione = mysql_connect($this->nomehost, $this->nomeuser, $this->password) or die(mysql_error()))) {

            mysql_select_db($this->nomedb, $this->connessione) or die(mysql_error());
            $this->attiva = TRUE; // Now this becomes useful, because the value has been set

        }

        return $this->attiva;

    } 

    // Method to build up the query

    public function query($sql) {

        return mysql_query($sql, $this->connessione);

    }

    // Method to extract information from the query

    public function estrai($query) {

        return mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    }

    public function disconnetti() {

        // More straight forward way to return the status

        if($this->attiva) return mysql_close($this->connessione);

        return FALSE;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since You `method="post"` for form. Your variables is always `$_POST['form_item_name']`
example:

```
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='text' name='username'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

In PHP part, after submiting form you can use you value as `$_POST['username']`.
Additionally you can use method='get' at HTML part, and variable will be passed in address bar. If you want to use GET variable it would be `$_GET['username']`.
Keep in mind that GET variables have limited space (i'm not sure but I think it's 255characters) So if you want pass long text it may fail.

And remember all the time, never trust what user enter, if you sure, that value must be number always check in php or it's number, if it's string you can use `mysql_real_escape_string();` to prevent MySQL injections.

Your code should be changed to:

$post_sql = $data->query("INSERT INTO `intse`.`products` (`id`, `name`, `cat`, `price`) VALUES ('$_POST[element_1]', '$_POST[element_2]', '$_POST[element_4]', '$_POST[element_3_1]');");

I advice you to use mysql_real_escape_string before that (if you know want why write to any field something like:

> ' x' 'x'x 'x

And you should get mysql sintax error. To fix that use code below:

```
$element1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['element_1']);
$element2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['element_2']);
$element31 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['element_3_1']);
$element4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['element_4']);

$post_sql = $data->query("INSERT INTO `intse`.`products` (`id`, `name`, `cat`, `price`) VALUES ('$element1', '$element2', '$element4', '$element31');");
```

Make Sure You are connected to database before using `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: I've write down your code, but "Notice: Use of undefined constant element_1 - assumed 'element_1' in D:\wamp\www\intse\pages\f\addform.php on line 22"

Comment: he forgot quotation marks: `$element1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['element_1']);` and so on.

Comment: Thanks to all, now the error is similar but changed...
Notice: Undefined index: element_1 in D:\wamp\www\intse\pages\f\addform.php on line 22

Comment: You still forgot to use `isset()`. Look at my answer above.

Comment: @jreuab Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Forgot a `)` before the first &&. I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks, but now the error is the same "Notice: Undefined index: element_1". and another question, when i load the page it will automatically fill the db row with null text, What should I do to make sure that adds the text only If this is done click on the add button?

Comment: The code we provided should have done that. Please provide your current code.

Comment: Well I'm not sure why i get downvoted, I didn't do check isset() but  I didn't provide full file, just parts of file which was necessary to get idea how things works in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$post_sql = $data->query("INSERT INTO `intse`.`products` (`id`, `name`, `cat`, `price`) VALUES ('element_1', 'element_2', 'element_4', 'element_3_1');");
```

You want to use

```
if (isset($_POST["element_1"]) && isset($_POST["element_2"]) && isset($_POST["element_3"]) && isset($_POST["element_4"]))
    $post_sql = $data->query("INSERT INTO `intse`.`products` (`id`, `name`, `cat`, `price`) VALUES ('".$_POST['element_1']."', '".$_POST['element_2']."', '".$_POST['element_4']."', '".$_POST['element_3_1']."');");
```

The $_POST superglobal array contains all data that is sent via POST. Regarding that, make sure, that your `inputs` are inside a `form` with `method` POST.

But that's not exactly what you want either, as that would leave SQL-injections possible.

Please use `prepared statements` or `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: element_1 in intse\pages\f\addform.php on line 28

Comment: I updated my answer, forgot the most important thing

Comment: Look at the if-condition that checks if the data was being sent.

Comment: I don't understand, this "<form id="form_824225" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">" must to go in php code right?

Comment: so i must to add the method post to the field? but i have <input>, can i add method="post" to input tag?

can you, if you want, correct my code to working?

Comment: Your HTML seems to be okay. Just replace the first line I posted in your example with the second line I posted.